# Accessing fields in objects in list of objects

Tags: java, list, object

I have a hashmap of objects called Members. And within those members I have an arraylist of more objects called Content. Last of all in the Content, I have various fields. How do I access these fields?

Inputting the data was not too hard as I created the Member object, then the Content object, added the Content to the Member and then added the Member to the hashmap.

I'm just finding it difficult to access the fields within the Content.

Below is some of my code from the Member class and from the Content class. I do have various getters and setters for each field but i left them out as i thought it would take up too much space

```
public class Member {
    private String _name;
    private String _nickname;
    private ArrayList<Content> _contentList = new ArrayList<Content>();

    public Member(String name, String nickname){
        setName(name);
        setNickname(nickname);
    }
    public ArrayList<Content> getContent() {
        return _contentList;
    }
    public void setContent(Content content) {
        _contentList.add(content);
    }
}    


public class Content {
    private String _type;
    private String _title;
    private String _visibility;
    private ArrayList<String> _tags = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Content(String type, String title, String visibility, String tags){
        setType(type);
        setTitle(title);
        setVisibility(visibility);
        setTags(tags);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: either make the fields public or write a public method to return the field values.

Comment: `setContent(Content content)` I would also change the name to `addContent` - could be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `members` is the `HasMap` then in order to retrieve the value of the field `title` of `Content` do the following:

```
Member member = members.get(<<your key here>>);
String title = member.getContent().get(<<index of the element of the list you want>>).getTitle();
```